# formatting time from datetime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have a `datetime` column in format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS`. Is it possible to just display time in format: `HH:mm:ss.SSS` and not the complete datetime itself?

I am trying the following, but it does not seem to do anything to the format:

```
{name: 'somedate', field: 'event_date', cellFilter: 'date:\'HH:MM:SS.SSS\''}
```

**EDIT**

This is how the grid is defined:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{name: 'somedata', field: 'event_date'}],
    data: [ {event_date: "2016-03-10 10:10:11.123"}]
}
```

Comment: which is the field and where do you want to display it. It is not clear

Comment: Angular will treat ISO 8601 strings as datetime objects, or you could convert your string to a moment or date object. Then in the HTML you can apply the [angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: This might help https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4806, I think going for the custom filter is a practical solution for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular in order to display the time part of a date is as simple as using `| date:'HH:mm:ss'`:

**HTML**

```
  <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

This `1288323623006` is equal to your date value field; but you can replace with your field name in your code.

Or you could do this in your controller after injecting `$filter`:

```
var formatedDate = $filter('date')(1288323623006, 'HH:mm:ss');
```

Here is the full example

```
angular.module('dateFormat', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$filter', function($scope,$filter) {

     $scope.formatedDate = $filter('date')(1288323623006, 'HH:mm:ss');

   }]);
```

Comment: Just if someone else stumbles upon this, this is what I ended up using instead: `cellFilter: "date:\'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss'"`

Answer (score 1):

Case matters.  You want `HH:mm:ss.sss`

Comment: This works if used with: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss` , but I want to use only time in this format..

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change your cell filter like this

```
cellFilter: 'date:\' HH:mm:ss\''
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can directly change it in the columnDefs as follows:

```
cellTemplate: "<span>{{grid.getCellValue(row,col) | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</span>"
```